# Getting public URL of newly uploaded CloudFiles asset

Tags: rackspace, cloudfiles

When uploading new asset into the CloudFiles storage I want to get public URL of this asset (if container is CDN-enabled). I figured out the only way to do this is to issue 3 (yes, three!) requests to RackSpace:

1. Authenticate user and get `x-auth-token`, `x-storage-url` and `x-cdn-management-url`.
2. After getting all the tokens and URLs, upload a file to the container.
3. Issue a HEAD request to the `x-cdn-management-url` for public URL of the container.

I just want to make sure that I really need 3 requests per upload to get the public URL of the asset I just uploaded. All the operations must be performed programmatically via API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that once you have your container's CDN URL, every object you put in it is appended to it. So, if your container's CDN URL is `cdn1.foo.cloudstorage.com`, your objects will have the URLs `cdn1.foo.cloudstorage.com/object1.ext`, `cdn1.foo.cloudstorage.com/object2.ext`, etc.

You only need the three steps to get the initial container CDN URL. Afterwards, it's simple.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Java, PHP, or Python, checkout one of the [Rackspace SDKs](http://developer.rackspace.com/). For examples on how to use CDN with each see:

1. Java: [CloudFilesPublish.java](https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds-examples/blob/master/rackspace/src/main/java/org/jclouds/examples/rackspace/cloudfiles/CloudFilesPublish.java)
2. PHP: [cdn.php](https://github.com/rackspace/php-opencloud/blob/master/samples/objectstore/cdn.php)
3. Python: [container_cdn.py](https://github.com/rackspace/pyrax/blob/master/samples/cloudfiles/container_cdn.py)